# F# does not exits when there are runtime errors inside async block

Tags: f#

When I have a runtime error like this one

```
type Msg = Any

type Agent() =

    let agent =
        MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
            let rec messageLoop (oldState) =
                async {

                    let! msg = inbox.Receive()
                    printfn "1"

                    match msg with
                    | Any ->

                        printfn "2"

                        let neverFound=
                          oldState
                          |> List.find (fun x -> x = 42)

                        printfn "3" // <- never happens, because I tried to find something that does not exists
                        return! messageLoop (oldState @ [neverFound])
                }

            printfn "0"
            messageLoop ([ 1; 2; 3 ]))

    member __.Post a = agent.Post a

let agent = Agent()
agent.Post ( Any)
```

it doest crash, the error is completely silent, but if I do explicitly try .. with:

```
type Msg = Any

type Agent() =

    let agent =
        MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
            let rec messageLoop (oldState) =
                async {

                    let! msg = inbox.Receive()
                    printfn "1"

                    match msg with
                    | Any ->

                        printfn "2"
                        try
                          let neverFound=
                            oldState
                            |> List.find (fun x -> x = 42)

                          printfn "3" 
                          return! messageLoop (oldState @ [neverFound])

                        with e ->
                          printfn "%A" e <-- does print
                          printfn "4"
                }

            printfn "0"
            messageLoop ([ 1; 2; 3 ]))

    member __.Post a = agent.Post a

let agent = Agent()
agent.Post ( Any)
```

if does catches the error.

This is not the only place this happens, apparently, errors that happen inside async are silent? How can I prevent this? Is there a flag one can run with no silent errors? or maybe a global async error handler?

Comment: It's not `async`, it's the `MailboxProcessor`.

Comment: I usually bother to figure out whether an actor (as in this case), a thread, a Task, an Async, needs an outer exception handler or not, in order for exceptions not to get swallowed silently and maybe even corrupt the application or system.

Comment: Thank you guys, I thought it was the async, because it also silently fails in Giraffe, I guess I don’t know enough yet about error handling in F# as am not quite sure where a try..with should be placed even. Thank you so much for your knowledge 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. You don't expect actors to crash on receiving a message.

`Start` is essentially:

```
   Async.Start(async { try do! body x with exn -> trigger exn })
```

So if you expose `MailboxProcessor.Error` with

```
member _.Error  = agent.Error
```

and listen to it:

```
agent.Error 
|> Observable.subscribe(fun (err) -> printfn "Oh no, an error: %s" err.Message) 
|> ignore
```

you will indeed see:

```
Oh no, an error: An index satisfying the predicate was not found in the collection.
```

Comment: Wooow I didn’t knew this existed, guess I need to read more about the mailbox processor to understand how to use them properly.

Comment: Is your question answered?

Comment: Yes, thank you, if you have any links or references where ti study this, I would greatly appreciate it.